# "Stay on" or "stay behind" in conext

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Could you tell whether I have to use *stay on* or *stay behind* in the following context?

> We had a meeting today and after it finished, the boss asked me to **stay** **on**/**behind** to talk about my new idea.

What I am trying to say is that the boss asked me to stay after everyone left. While I am at it, would it also be natural to say the following?

> We had a meeting today and after it finished, the boss **held** me **up** to talk about my new idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stay behind** makes more sense in your context. Compare the definitions in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stay_on vs https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stay_behind

The second definition there of "Stay Behind" matches what you're looking for:

> 2. (idiomatic) To remain where one is, whilst others leave.

The second statement is natural, except the 'for' is unnecessary:

> We had a meeting today and after it finished, the boss held me up to talk about my new idea

Note that "the boss held me up" carries a negative connotation (at least for me, as an American English speaker). Holding someone up implies an unwanted delay. The second definition for https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hold_up:

> 2. (transitive) To impede; detain